# Unable enable iOS & Android on Facebook App Center Listed Platforms

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-app-center

I have my app approved and listed on Facebook for sometime already. Today, I try to enable `iOS - iPhone`, `iOS - iPad`, and `Android` in `App Center Listed Platforms` section to get `Send to Mobile` button on my app listing.

[image]

By default these buttons are disabled, I can't enable it. After I enable `Single Sign On` for `iOS` and `Android` on setting page, I am able to enable it. But as soon as I enable any of it, Facebook will display the following for my app:

```
Misconfigured App
Sorry, Myappname hasn't been approved for display in App Center.
```

How can I solve it?